# PHP - regex as array key

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I need to set regex as array key for routes in my page to accept year. What do i mean:

```
$segment = URL::segment(0); //get first segment for example login, or 2015 - as year

$routes = [ 
"/" => "home.php",
"login" => "login.php",
"some_regex_here" => "year_posts.php"
]

//now check if $segment exists in array $routes
if(isset($routes[$segment])
   URL::redirect($routes[$segment]);
else
   URL::show404();//page in $segment isn't available in $routes array
```

Now when i go to `localhost/2015`, `$segment` will be `2015`, so it matches regex condition in key and it should redirect me to `year_posts.php`.
Do you have any ideas how to do it ?

Comment: Sorry, this does not make any sense. At least none you were able to explain. An array does not do any redirections, not can you "go to" one. So why don't you describe what your _real_ question is? If your question simply is "what regex does match the string "localhost/2015"", then I suggest you read a basic introduction to regular expressions. It your question is something else, then say so.

Comment: No, you don't understand me.
I get URL `$segment` like `2015`. Now I look to `$routes` array where I have to redirect user according to segment as key array. If segment matches regex(some valid year), `redirect($routes[$segment])`, whereas key 2015 doesn't exists in array, but it matches regex. 
I hope that you already know what I mean.

Comment: If so, then why don't you tell so in your question? And if so, then what _is_ your question? Apart from what the regex for "2015" is? I repeat: start reading an introduction to regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the regex:

Quick and diry: This will check if the string is just four (numerical) digits:

```
'/^\d\d\d\d$/'
```

Can also be written as:

```
'/^\d{4}$/'
```

If you want to check for a certain year range, it gets more complicated. E.g. use this for 2010 through 2015:

```
'/^201[0-5]$/'
```

Now for the PHP: You cannot use a regex as an array key. You probably need another `if`, like this:

```
if(preg_match('/^201[0-5]$/', $segment))
{
  URL::redirect("year_posts.php");
}
elseif(isset($routes[$segment])
{
  URL::redirect($routes[$segment]);
}
else
{
  URL::show404();//page in $segment isn't available in $routes array
}
```